# Pandas change values based on previous value in same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 1, 1], 
                         'Date' : [datetime.date(year=2022,month=5,day=1), datetime.date(year=2022,month=11,day=1),
                                                       datetime.date(year=2022,month=10,day=1), datetime.date(year=2022,month=11,day=1)], 
                         "Lifecycle ID": [5,5,5,5]})
```

And I need to change the lifecycle based on the lifecycle 6 month ago (if it was 5, it should always be 6 (not +1)).

I'm currently trying:

```
df.loc[(df["Date"] == (df["Date"] - pd.DateOffset(months=6))) & (df["Lifecycle ID"] == 5), "Lifecycle ID"] = 6
```

However Pandas is **not considering the ID** and I don't know how.

The output should be this dataframe (only last Lifecycle ID changed to 6):

[image]

Could you please help me here?

Comment: What is your expected output based on the sample DataFrame?

Comment: Can you please specify *"if it was 5, it should be 6"*? Do you want the value 6 months ago +1? Or really if 5 then 6, otherwise don't change it?

Comment: I've added an image of the expected output. If the Lifecycle ID was a '5'   6 month ago then it should be a '6' otherwise it should not change

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not fully clear, but if I guess correctly:

```
# ensure datetime type
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# add the time delta to form a helper DataFrame
df2 = df.assign(Date=df['Date'].add(pd.DateOffset(months=6)))

# merge on ID/Date, retrieve "Lifecycle ID"
# and check if the value is 5
m = df[['ID', 'Date']].merge(df2, how='left')['Lifecycle ID'].eq(5)

# if it is, update the value
df.loc[m, 'Lifecycle ID'] = 6
```

If you want to increment the value automatically from the value 6 months ago:

```
s = df[['ID', 'Date']].merge(df2, how='left')['Lifecycle ID']

df.loc[s.notna(), 'Lifecycle ID'] = s.add(1)
```

Output:

```
   ID       Date  Lifecycle ID
0   1 2022-05-01             5
1   2 2022-11-01             5
2   1 2022-10-01             5
3   1 2022-11-01             6
```